# mat-date-range-input isn't known element [Angular material]

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

The problem is that I can't use `<mat-date-range-input>` Material Component because I get an error:

[image]

I have a module called "**Material module**" and there's an import and export of `MatNativeDateModule` and `MatDatepickerModule`. This module is imported into module I'm working with.

I can use simple `mat-datepicker` and it works properly.

Can anybody help me with that?

10.1.2 - version of Material

Comment: Can you add it to stackblitz?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you on an older version of Angular, but on version 10.1.2 of material?

`mat-date-range-input` doesn't work on Angular versions lower than 10.0.2. To take advantage of this, you have to update your application, this is pretty straightforward if you are on version 9. I faced the same issue and after updating the range date picker is working.

For detailed information of how to update go to: https://update.angular.io/.

These imports also have to be in the `app.module.ts`

```
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I spent all day trying to deal with ng update, but I just updated with `npm install` and it heplped, thanks a lot

Comment: @Prateek Upadhyay is there any other option except updating the application version

Answer (score 1):

It required importing the ReactiveFormsModule also

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Answer (score 0):

importing this dependeces:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core'
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker'
```

In your module.